# systemd-nspawn environment variables

Tags: systemd, containers

I created a systemd-nspawn container and set the environment variables in the matching `.nspawn` file (for example `DISPLAY=:0`). Upon booting the container, the variables are correctly passed to PID 1:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/1/environ 
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin...(omitted)...DISPLAY=:0
```

However, the environment variables are not passed to the `bash` login shell. Why?

```
$ env
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  ...(etc, no DISPLAY variable)...
```

I expected that the login shell will inherit the environment variables from PID 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default systemd does not pass environment variables set for systemd to executed processes. This behaviour can be changed by using `PassEnvironment=` for the systemd units inside the container where you would like to access the environment variables, see [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for details.